# Script to change the value of a variable

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I've currently got a tab switching script set-up but the tekst that belongs with the tabs doesnt want to play ball. I figured a solution for that but for that i need some kind of script or function that can change the value of $number from 1 to 2 and back. The catch is that the number needs to depend on what class another li has. The li is not related to the $number or the place where the text is so using .parent .sibling or anything like that is not possible.

The li get a class which is active. If i can get a script/function checking which of the two li's has the class 'active' and set the $number accordingly.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.tab_table .tab-links a').on('click', function(e) {
            var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

            // Show/Hide Tabs
            $('.tab_table ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

            // Change/remove current tab to active
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
<tabs class="entry-content">
    <div class="tab_table">
        <ul class="tab-links">
            <?php if(get_field( 'tab_1_-_naam', $id)): ?>
            <li class="active <?php echo $id; ?>-1">
                <a href="#<? echo $slug; ?>_tab_<?php echo $id; ?>-1">
                    <?php the_field( 'tab_1_-_naam', $id); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>


            <?php if(get_field( 'tab_2_-_naam', $id)): ?>
            <li class="<?php echo $id; ?>-2">
                <a "this.style.color='#5D3B08!important';" href="#<? echo $slug; ?>_tab_<?php echo $id; ?>-2">
                    <?php the_field( 'tab_2_-_naam', $id); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php $number=1 ; $tab_tekst='tab_' .$number. '_-_tekst'; ?>
        <div class="panes">
            <?php if( li class==a ctive.$id-1) { ?>
            <?php if(get_field( 'tab_1_-_tekst', $id)): ?>
            <div id="<? echo $slug; ?>_tab_<?php echo $id; ?>-1" class="tab-content active">
                <p>
                    <?php the_field($tab_tekst, $id);?>
                </p>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to set a php variable depending on your javascript?

Comment: No, the javascript gives the li's a class (.active) i want to set a php variable depending on what li has that class.

Comment: In short script sets the li class and depending on the class you want to set the php variable. From client side code you are trying to set the value for server variable?

Comment: Thinking about it, thats probably not the safest way to approach this situation. Would it be possible to edit the javascript to not only make it switch the class but at the same time switch the variable of $number?